# How would I create a string option in my slash command that reads the string that the user sent in, and uses that as an argument?

Tags: discord.js, distube

So I have a verified Discord.JS bot, and I've been trying to create a slash command with music (Distube). I want to register the play command, and then, allow the user to input a string (the song title) and use that and play the song. How would I do this?

This is my command file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {

    name: "play",
    description: "Play music!",

    async execute (interaction, client) {
    
    const music = args.join(" ");

    client.distube.play(message, music)

    }
}
```

Like I said, how would I change this to match the slash command? I'm using the [Discord.JS v13 Guide](https://discordjs.guide) for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the [Slash Command Guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html)

Comment: This is very broad question about implementation. Also, check [Slash Command Guide - options](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#options) to get an idea about taking inputs with slash commands.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `const music = interaction.options.get("query").value` instead of `const music = args.join(' ')` because d.js v13 slash commands using interactions, not arguments.

For getting bot joining your voice, you should use `client.distube.playVoiceChannel`, for searching user voice, we need get this also from interaction, `const voice = interaction.member.voice.channel`

After this, your code should look like this:

```
const music = interaction.options.get("query").value
const voice = interaction.member.voice.channel
client.distube.play(voice, music)
```